# AZURE - Error 400 bad request - Upload VM on-Premises

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-powershell

I tried to upload a vhd (virtual machine - 200GB) to Azure, but I get this error:

> The remote server returned and error (400) Bad Request.

However, I have managed to load different a vhd without problem (60GB).

Any idea to solve this error?

[image: screenshot of error message]

Answer (score 0):

Have you creating a container manually on azure portal? could you please print the `$urlOfUploadedImageVhd`, in Azure, it has some limitations on what name you can give containers.

If you request a container with an invalid name, it will result in (400) Bad Request, which you are getting. So check your "containerName" string.

For test, you can create a container manually, then upload VHD via PowerShell.

Note:

In Azure, the container name was all **lowercase**.

Comment: Does it work now? Please let me know if you would like further assistance.